# Android pending intents issue and global class

Tags: android, global-variables, android-pendingintent

So, my app, has multiple activities.

One of them displays a list of messages (retrieved from a local SQLite).

I also have a GlobalClass that extends Application and I use it in order to store  some values between activities.
Like this:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalClass extends Application {
private String uzid;
...
public String getUzer() {
    return uzid;
}

public void setUzer(String aUzer) {
    uzid = aUzer;
}
```

My app, of course has a login page, where user authenticates itself before gaining access to the app. When he does that, I set a userId integer in my GlobalClass with the id number of the logged user.
Until now, nothing fancy.

I also have a sync adapter that checks for new messages on a remote server and synchronizes the 2 tables (local and remote). And when the sync adapter finds new messages on the remote server, it generates an Android Notification. When user clicks on the notification, my app opens and the activity with the inbox shows up displaying all messages.

I noticed that from time to time, my globalClass userID is empty, even though when I start the app, you cannot get passed the login activity without setting it.
So the app absolutelly sets this globalClass value.

So my guess is that when my android notification is clicked, and the activity with the message list is shown, somehow the globalClass is re-initialized ?!?!?!?!

Is there any way of making sure this does not happen?

I really need my user to be able to use the app just like never happened when he starts it from the notification bar by clicking on the notification.
I mean, the user logs in, GlobalClass userId is being set, then the app goes on. After a a while it enters pause, display shuts down, then a new message arrives and a notification is shown. The user clicks it and my app is brought back to the display showing messages, but the userId is null now.
Why?
And how to prevent this?

This is how I show the notification when a new message is found in the syncAdapter:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MesajeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //(context, 0, intent, 0);
        // Build notification
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Message from "+ self.getSursanume())
                .setContentText(self.getTitlu()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_50)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        noti.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.htc4);
        noti.number = i;
        notificationManager.notify(i, noti);
```

What is wrong here?
I use the current user id (found in GlobalClass) to identify the messages that are intended for the current user, so in onCreate, and also in onResume I instantiate my GlobalClass and retrieve the userID. But this crashes my app. Because sometimes when entering the app from the notification, my global variable "userID" is NULL.

How do I make this problem go away?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that from time to time, my globalClass userID is empty, even though when I start the app, you cannot get passed the login activity without setting it. So the app absolutelly sets this globalClass value.

First, your app may not be started to launch an activity (e.g., app started to send a command to a service).

Second, your app may not be started to launch your login activity (e.g., user came back to you from recent-tasks list).

> So my guess is that when my android notification is clicked, and the activity with the message list is shown, somehow the globalClass is re-initialized ?!?!?!?!

Your process was terminated in between invocations. This is [perfectly normal](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).

> Is there any way of making sure this does not happen?

Not really. Processes go away all the time, on all operating systems, for any number of reasons (e.g., crashes, manual termination by the user).

> I really need my user to be able to use the app just like never happened when he starts it from the notification bar by clicking on the notification.

Then you are going to need to persist your data. Static data members, including custom `Application` objects, are **only a cache**.

Or, rather than having a "login activity", have it be some sort of fragment that you can display in any of your activities when authentication is needed.

Or, have your `Notification` route to the "login activity", which would determine that authentication is not needed and forwards the user along to the end destination. If, OTOH, authentication is needed, the "login activity" handles this, *then* forwards the user along to the end destination.

Comment: In this case, I think I have a new solution. Since I use SQLite and it is not a cache, but persistent, I will replace getting the userId from the globalClass with getting it from the DB. So when logging in, I set the logged in user as active. Then later on in onResum and OnCreate of my activities that need the userID, I simply query the SQLite users table for the user that is active and get the id from there. Does this solution have any flaw in your opinion?

Comment: @user1137313: "I think I have a new solution" -- you are describing the first of the three that I outlined in my answer's closing paragraphs. "Does this solution have any flaw in your opinion?" -- somebody could hack into the database and change the active user ID. I have no idea how big of a problem this would be for your app, as I don't know much about your app.

Comment: You suggested "persisting" my data, you are right. But since my expereience is not that vast with Android, I did not automatically assume that you meant using my DB. I thought maybe there are more ways to persist data. Your answer was anyway going to be accepted.

Comment: My app is not going to the PlayStore, it will only be installed on a selected 30 tablets, and will be used by my customer's employees. The risc of someone hacking the DB is rather small. Is there ANY OTHER WAY of persisting my data, for the purpose described in the question?

Comment: @user1137313: A database is a type of file. You are welcome to store your data in any other type of file. Standard Java file I/O works, for [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) (though, in your case, internal storage would be the better solution, as it is private to your app). You could also use `SharedPreferences`, which is just a thin veneer over an XML file for one-off bits of data.